# Grouping a ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> according to a value, and adding another value with respect to the sorted key

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have a ArrayList>> which holds certain key-value entries. Like:-

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("NewId", newId);
    map.put("Title", title);
    map.put("Description", description);
    mList.add(map);

MyList myList = new MyList(mList);

itemsAdapter = new LazyAdapter(myContext, myList);

            newList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

"NewId" can be similar for multiple entries.

Also I have an Array of colours:-

```
String[] colors = new String[]{"#1F1A17", "#62934D", "#F9B03F", "#7959BC", "#74B8DE", "#E65641", "#7CC8BB", "#D7CE5D", "#D6BE95", "#B694D1"};
```

I want a mew group with all the entries with same "NewId" together and assign them the first colour, other entries with next similar "NewId" with the second colour and so on till items with first 10 same "NewId" get assigned with their respective colours.

eg:- before grouping

```
NewId  Title  Description
 101   title1  des1
 102   title2  des2
 103   title3  des3 
 101   title4  des4
 102   title5  des5
 103   title6  des6
```

After grouping,

```
NewId  Title  Description
 101   title1  des1  ------> color1
 101   title4  des4  ------> color1
 102   title2  des2  ------> color2
 102   title5  des5  ------> color2
 103   title3  des3  ------> color3
 103   title6  des6  ------> color3
```

What I have done yet:-

```
    public class MyList {

        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

public MyList(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist)
    {
        this.list = mylist;
    }


        public boolean add(HashMap<String, String> map) {
            return list.add(map);
        }

        public void setColor(String newId, String color) {
            for (HashMap<String, String> m : list)
                if (m.containsKey(newId))
                    m.put("color", color);
        }

        public String getGroupKey(String key, int i) {      
            ArrayList<String> uniqeList = getUniqKeyList(key);
            Collections.sort(uniqeList);
            return uniqeList.get(i);
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getUniqKeyList(String key){
            ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
            for (HashMap<String, String> m : list)
                if(!l.contains(m.get(key)))
                    l.add(m.get(key));
            return l;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            MyList myList = new MyList();
            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            map.put("NewId", newId);
            map.put("Title", title);
            map.put("Description", description);
            myList.add(map);

            String[] colors = new String[]{"#1F1A17", "#62934D","#B694D1"};

            int i=0;
            while (true) {
                        if(i == colors.length) 
                                break;
                String s =  myList.getGroupKey("NewId", i);
                if(s == null)
                    break;
                else 
                    myList.setColor(s, colors[i++]);
            }       
        }

itemsAdapter = new LazyAdapter(myContext, myList);
```

But I get an error:-

```
04-24 04:57:49.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1882): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
04-24 04:57:49.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1882):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
04-24 04:57:49.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1882):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
04-24 04:57:49.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1882):     at Utility.MyList.getGroupKey(MyList.java:58)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try...

  while (true) {
                        if(i >= colors.length) 
                                break;
                String s =  myList.getGroupKey("NewId", i);
                if(s == null)
                    break;
                else 
                    myList.setColor(s, colors[i++]);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. but I still get the same  error. The error is at the `MyList.getGroupKey()`